# What is query id ("qid") in XGBoost

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost, ranking

In XGBoost [documentation](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/input_format.html) it's said that for ranking applications we can specify query group ID's **qid** in the training dataset as in the following snippet:

```
1 qid:1 101:1.2 102:0.03
0 qid:1 1:2.1 10001:300 10002:400
0 qid:2 0:1.3 1:0.3
1 qid:2 0:0.01 1:0.3
0 qid:3 0:0.2 1:0.3
1 qid:3 3:-0.1 10:-0.3
0 qid:3 6:0.2 10:0.15
```

I have a couple of questions regarding **qid**'s (standard LTR setup set of search queries and documents, they are represented by query, document and query-document features):

1) Let's say we have **qid**'s in our training file. Does it mean that the optimization will be performed only on a per query basis, all other features specified will be considered as document features and cross-query learning won't happen?

2) Let's assume that queries are represented by query features. Should we still have **qid**'s specified in the training file or we should just list query, document and query-document features?

**UPDATE:**

So far, I have the following explanation, but how correct or incorrect it is I don't know:

Each row in the training set is for a query-document pair, so in each row we have query, document and query-document features. If we specify "qid" as a unique query ID for each query (=query group) then we can assign weight to each of these query groups. If the weight in some query group is large, then XGBoost will try to make the ranking correct for this group first.

From a [file in XGBoost repo](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/911a902835e9683e77950093ed756007910a8db2/tests/python/test_ranking.py):

```
weights = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0])
...
dtrain = xgboost.DMatrix(X, label=y, weight=weights)
...
# Since we give weights 1, 2, 3, 4 to the four query groups,
# the ranking predictor will first try to correctly sort the last query group
# before correctly sorting other groups.
```

and [also](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/71a8b8c65afcad6a3e3bf48bf1ee5e66d762543f/python-package/xgboost/sklearn.py):

```
In ranking task, one weight is assigned to each query group
(not each data point). This is because we only care about the
relative ordering of data points within each group, so it
doesn't make sense to assign weights to individual data points.
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Found this [link](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/tj/svm_light/svm_rank.html).  Given

```
3 qid:1 1:1 2:1 3:0 4:0.2 5:0 # 1A
2 qid:1 1:0 2:0 3:1 4:0.1 5:1 # 1B
1 qid:1 1:0 2:1 3:0 4:0.4 5:0 # 1C
1 qid:1 1:0 2:0 3:1 4:0.3 5:0 # 1D 
1 qid:2 1:0 2:0 3:1 4:0.2 5:0 # 2A 
2 qid:2 1:1 2:0 3:1 4:0.4 5:0 # 2B
1 qid:2 1:0 2:0 3:1 4:0.1 5:0 # 2C
1 qid:2 1:0 2:0 3:1 4:0.2 5:0 # 2D 
2 qid:3 1:0 2:0 3:1 4:0.1 5:1 # 3A
3 qid:3 1:1 2:1 3:0 4:0.3 5:0 # 3B
4 qid:3 1:1 2:0 3:0 4:0.4 5:1 # 3C
1 qid:3 1:0 2:1 3:1 4:0.5 5:0 # 3D
```

the following set of pairwise constraints is generated (examples are referred to by the info-string after the # character):

```
1A>1B, 1A>1C, 1A>1D, 1B>1C, 1B>1D, 2B>2A, 2B>2C, 2B>2D, 3C>3A, 3C>3B, 3C>3D, 3B>3A, 3B>3D, 3A>3D
```

So **qid** seems to specify groups such that within each group relevance values can be compared to each other and between groups relevance values can't be directly compared (inc. during the training procedure). So during training we need to have **qid**'s and during inference we don't need them as input.

Thank you!

Comment: cross-posted at https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/453670/232706

Comment: @Ben Reiniger Please, let me know which site is a better fit for the question and I'll remove another one.

Comment: The substantial overlap between sites makes it hard to say which is better; I'd suggest to keep both at least until one of them is answered.  Having the cross-post link (in my comment) makes it easier to prevent duplication of work.

Answer (score 5):

In ranking applications of information retrieval, training data consists of queries and documents matching them together with relevance degree of each match.

For example when searching in something in google, the training data may be prepared manually by human assessors (or raters, as Google calls them), who check results for some queries and determine relevance of each result.

It is not feasible to check the relevance of all documents, and so typically only the top few documents, retrieved by some existing ranking models are checked.

Training data is used by a learning algorithm to produce a ranking model that computes the relevance of documents for actual queries.

Rank profiles can have one or two phases:

1. Phase one should use a computationally inexpensive function to rank candidates
2. Phase two is run on a small candidate set

In short, the query selection and first phase ranking reduces the size of the computation - then machine-learned models can be used on the second-phase ranking on rerank-count documents per node. This makes the ranking scalable (see sizing):

- Control the second phase candidate set size
- Add content nodes to rank less documents per node

[image: A possible architecture of a machine-learned search engine.]

Let's now answer your questions:

> 1) Let's say we have qid's in our training file. Does it mean that the optimization will be performed only on a per-query basis, all other features specified will be considered as document features and cross-query learning won't happen?

It means that in order to rank all candidates it will rank only the first ones in order to be computationally less expensive. So it will only look in the first query for the extensive ranking search.

> 2)Let's assume that queries are represented by query features. Should we still have qid's specified in the training file or we should just list query, document and query-document features?

Yes, the rank_feature query is typically used so its relevance scores are added to other scores query.

Note that qid's are only used in training set https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/issues/1398

Sources:
 - [Wikipedia - Learning to rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_to_rank)
 - [Vespa - Tank](https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/ranking.html)
 - [Vespa - Phased Ranking](https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/phased-ranking.html)
 - [Elastic - Rank feature query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-rank-feature-query.html)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I'm aware of two-stage procedure in such systems, but I don't get your answers to my questions. So what is exactly "qid" in the context of XGBoost? 
"So it will only look in the first query for the extensive ranking search.", "Yes, the rank_feature query is typically used so its relevance scores are added to other scores query." - sorry, I don't get these parts, can you please elaborate?

Comment: Did you check in the vespa documentation? it seems useful and thorough. Maybe tonight i have more free time and i am able to elaborate more